# PHP echo array by value in loop or foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a list of skills and industries in a table which is fetched into a multidimensional array like the below. There are over 300 rows in the table:

```
$skills = 
    [0] => Array ([rowID] => 10000169 [industry] => Engineering and manufacturing [skill] => 3D Modelling)
    [1] => Array ([rowID] => 10000083 [industry] => Accountancy, banking and finance [skill] => AAT)
    [2] => Array ([rowID] => 10000079 [industry] => Accountancy, banking and finance [skill] => CT600)
    [3] => Array ([rowID] => 10000102 [industry] => Business, consulting and management [skill] => WIP)
    [4] => Array ([rowID] => 10000078 [industry] => Accountancy, banking and finance [skill] => ACCA)
    [5] => Array ([rowID] => 10000095 [industry] => Internet and technology [skill] => HTML)
```

...

I'm trying to echo out each industry with the relevant skills in a list to look like the below:

**Accountancy, banking and finance**
10000083, AAT
10000078, ACCA
10000079, CT600

**Business, consulting and management**
10000102, WIP

**Engineering and manufacturing**
10000169, 3D Modelling

**Internet and technology**
10000095, HTML

At the moment I'm using a foreach so each one is listed one at a time but I really want to group them together. I've looked at array_filter and using a key but just can’t get what I wanted. Is it possible to do this from the array I have?

Comment: Why don't you order by `industry` rather than `id`?

Comment: Why is there a <br> element here? This doesn't seem to be a proper array construct. Are you sure this works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort data by industry then loop (echo title if different from previous one) :

```
   function cmp($a, $b)
    {
        return strcmp($a["industry"], $b["industry"]);
    }

    usort($skills, "cmp");
    $lastSkill = "";
    foreach($skills as $skill) {
     if ($skill["industry"] !== $lastSkill ) {
      echo "<h1>" . $skill["industry"] . "</h1>";
      $lastSkill = $skill["industry"];
     }
     echo "<br> - " . $skill["skill"] ;
    }
```

(You may also add an "`order by industry`" in your SQL query)

Comment: Thank you, this worked exactly as I wanted :)
I changed my select statement to order by industry and then skill then changed your code to this:
        $lastskill = '';
        foreach($skills as $skill) {
     if ($skill['industry'] !== $lastSkill ) {
         echo '<h3>'.$skill['industry'].'</h3>';
         $lastSkill = $skill["industry"];
     }
 echo '<br>'.$skill['skill'];
        }